# how to secure my symfony2 website even without using built-in firewall?

Tags: security, symfony

I am currently creating a website/web app using symfony2 framework. Since i found the firewall thing a bit difficult, i planned to use basic session related validation in order to secure some routes. is it ok? are there any better method? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using built-in firewall, then you will need to check for Granted Roles and whether user is authenticated or not which is going to be redundant lines of code and doesnt look that pretty.

Security Firewall is not that complex as you think and its very simple and straight forward .

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to **use** firewall

Try to read these articles:

- [Security: Basic Example: HTTP Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#basic-example-http-authentication)
- [How to customize your Form Login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html)
- [How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)